# xamarin form: Custom View in listview on android screw up

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, binding

I found xamarin render ui is very difficult.

I have a custom view inside the listview which contain a list of small icons. Each item may have some visible icon showing. I realized when i scrolled down to bottom and scroll back to the top, the one supposed to have that icon to be shown was not shown. I passed in an object into the custom view to tell which one to be displayed.

Item in listview, local:ChildInfoIconsView is the custom view.

```
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                                           Grid.Row="0" 
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start">                              
                                            <Label AutomationId="aChildName" Style="{StaticResource MediumBoldFont}" x:Name="childName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                            <local:ChildInfoIconsView 
                                                Child="{Binding .}"
                                                VerticalOptions="Fill">
                                            </local:ChildInfoIconsView> 
                                        </StackLayout>
```

Main Code for custom view

```
public partial class ChildInfoIconsView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty OrientationProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Orientation), typeof(StackOrientation), typeof(StackOrientation), StackOrientation.Vertical, BindingMode.OneWay, null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowClassroomProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowClassroom), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), true, BindingMode.OneWay, null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ChildProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Child), typeof(ChildModel), typeof(ChildModel), null, BindingMode.OneWay, null);

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(Child)))
        {
            if (Child != null)
            {
                this.ImageUnauth.IsVisible = (Child.HasUnauthorized.HasValue) ? Child.HasUnauthorized.Value : false;
                this.ImageMedical.IsVisible = (Child.HasMedical.HasValue) ? Child.HasMedical.Value : false;
                this.ImageBirthday.IsVisible = Child.IsBirthday;
                this.ImageNewChild.IsVisible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Child.NewChildFlagImage);
                this.ImageClassroom.IsVisible = (!ShowClassroom) ? false : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Child.Classroom);

                this.textClass.Text = Child.Classroom;
                this.textClass.IsVisible = (!ShowClassroom) ? false : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Child.Classroom);
            } 
        }
        else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(ShowClassroom)))
        {
            this.ImageClassroom.IsVisible = ShowClassroom;
            this.textClass.IsVisible = ShowClassroom;
        }
        else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(Orientation)))
        {
            this.layout.Orientation = Orientation;
        }
    }

    public ChildInfoIconsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public StackOrientation Orientation
    {
        get
        {
            return (StackOrientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowClassroom
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ShowClassroomProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ShowClassroomProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ChildModel Child
    {
        get
        {
            return (ChildModel)GetValue(ChildProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChildProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

It work fine when using old version of xamarin.forms. When updated the package, this happen on android.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms v3.5 and if yes did it work before you updated the packages? I know it did just making sure!

Comment: Yes i am currently updated to 3.5.0.1... can't remember the exact number at the moment. It does work when i was still in 2.?? something early version. Actually, the early code doesn't have the OnPropertyChanged and just have the ChildProperty which I use the getter / setting to update the views by calling OnPropertyChanged function

Comment: But then when i upgraded xamarin.forms and using the old code, those icons in the ChildInfoIconsView  no longer visible because of the ChildProperty not get called

Comment: I had a similar issue with xamarin forms 3.5 can you downgrade to 3.4 and see if that helps?